# Plots.jl - Map surface color to matrix

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I'm trying to figure out how to create surface plots with Plots.jl. I can create a spherical surface from a 2-d mesh like below:

[image]

```
using Plots
plotlyjs()
# Read the theta and phi angles from file...
x2d = sind(theta2d).*cosd(phi2d)
y2d = sind(theta2d).*sind(phi2d)
z2d = cosd(theta2d)
surface(x2d,y2d,z2d)
```

However, I want to have the surface color be controlled by a separate matrix like the plot below (made with Python).

[image]

```
from mayavi import mlab
# Create/read plot data...
mlab.figure(bgcolor=(1,1,1), fgcolor=(0.,0.,0.))
mlab.mesh(x2d, y2d, z2d, scalars=p2d, colormap='jet', vmax=5, vmin=-35)
```

Perhaps I should just use the Python plotting functions directly? Or maybe GLVisualize directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can supply the matrix controlling the colors as the `fill_z` keyword. It doesn't work on all backends, but try plotljys and pyplot.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - I tested with both PyPlot and PlotlyJS. Thanks!